# Can't open jpg file or pdf when I download a file in react-native

Tags: react-native, download

I want to download a file in my react-native app when I press a download button. And I was able to do it using this code:

```
const handleDownload = (item) => {
    let date = new Date();
    let file = item.url;
    let ext = getExtention(file);
    ext = '.' + ext[0];
    const { config, fs } = RNFetchBlob;
    let PictureDir = fs.dirs.PictureDir;
    let options = {
      fileCache: true,
      addAndroidDownloads: {
        // Related to the Android only
        useDownloadManager: true,
        notification: true,
        path:
          PictureDir +
          '/image_' +
          Math.floor(date.getTime() + date.getSeconds() / 2) +
          ext,
        description: 'Image',
      },
    };
    config(options)
      .fetch('GET', file)
      .then((res) => {
        dispatch(
          setToast({
            type: 'success',
            text1: t('business-categories.download_success'),
          })
        );
      });
  };
```

and it is successfully download, but whenever I try to open the file I get a toast error `Can't open file`.

Does anyone knows how to fix this ??

(EDIT)

I found out that the file downloaded is BIN FILE where the original file is a pdf file.
[image]

Is there a way that I can change this ?

Comment: Can you add a code snippet that throws an error you like: 'Can't open file'?

Comment: The error is not from the code. Its when you click on the file from the notification in android or file system @JigneshMayani

Comment: @warCommander can you check the file size of the downloaded file and see if the entire thing is downloaded?

Comment: yes the download size is the same as the one I uploaded @AbhishekSah

Comment: @warCommander, Can you match the file extensions?